# What is browser memory or virtual memory in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory

I have been studying react in depth and there's one thing which I am not understanding and have already spend so many hours on that.

So if we talk about virtual dom, we know:

**The virtual DOM (VDOM) is an in-memory representation of Real DOM. The representation of a UI is kept in memory and synced with the “real” DOM**

But can anyone please tell me what's memory here ?? Is it browser memory or system memory ? and if it's browser memory then where is it stored? I still didn't get this answer anywhere!

Also if we talk about **webpack-dev-server**, it serves content virtually and it doesn't writes to disk. But from where it servers ? where the content is stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for both React and webpack-dev-server is that they store the data in your [RAM memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory).

In the case of React, there's code that's synchronizing data from there to the DOM through the usage of DOM API.

Note that in case of webpack-dev-server, you can also force it to write to the disk but generally that's avoided (disk wear, a bit slower).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one quick question, what is browser memory then ? And does it have any limits ? And where the real dom is stored then ?

Comment: What do you mean by browser memory? There are many types of memories. For example `localStorage` or `IndexedDB` would store to the disk and the limits vary based on browser if I remember correctly.